# Return a Hash Grouped by Top Level Domains

Tags: ruby

I have an array of emails that I need to convert into a Hash using their Top Level Domain:

Example:

```
["kevin@yahoo.fr", "edward@gmail.fr", "julien@mdn.com", "dimitri@berlin.de"]

Should Return

{
  com:  ["julien@mdn.com"],
  de:   ["dimitri@berlin.de"],
  fr:   ["kevin@yahoo.fr", "edward@gmail.fr"]
}
```

What I have done so far.

```
def group_by_tld(emails)
  # TODO: return a Hash with emails grouped by TLD
  new_hash = {}
  emails.each do |e|
    last_el = e.partition(".").last
    if last_el == e.partition(".").last
      new_hash[last_el] = e
    else
      break
    end
  end
   return new_hash
end


Output: {"fr"=>"edward@gmail.fr", "com"=>"julien@mdn.com", "de"=>"dimitri@berlin.de"}
```

How can I fix so both values are in an array.

Thanks
Onur

Comment: I think you don't need that `break`. And that entire `if`, actually. Just fetch the last_el and add the email to the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix so both values are in an array.

You're not actually creating an array. Do create one and append values to it.

```
new_hash[last_el] ||= [] # make sure array exists, and don't overwrite it if it does
new_hash[last_el] << e
```

---

Alternatively, this whole snippet can be replaced with

```
emails.group_by{|e| e.partition(".").last }
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio! Just one question tho what exactly does "| | = []" do?

Comment: @OnurKaradeniz: what the comment says, makes sure that array exists. If you want to know more, the term is "memoization"